# Cursor movement shortcut for moving over n columns

Tags: excel

I am using Excel for Mac version 14. I also have the latest Libre office. My question is this:

Say I am in a cell, and I would like to move 5 columns over within the current row. Is there a keyboard shortcut to do this quickly in either programs mentioned above?

I can't seem to find anything on the net. Ideally, I'd like some vim-like shortcut, i.e. 5-rightarrow or some such combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel doesn't have this function on its own, but you can code it if you want (although I don't see a way around hard-coding the number of cells to be moved). To use your example, just create a new macro ( Developer > Macros > "FiveSpacesToTheRight" > Create ) with the following content:

```
Sub FiveSpacesToTheRight()
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Select
End Sub
```

Then associate the macro to a shortcut key ( Developer > Macros > "FiveSpacesToTheRight" > Options > Shortcut Key ).

Note: If you don't see the Developer tab, you'll need to enable it: File > Options > Customize Ribbon; then under the "Customize the Ribbon" panel, put a checkbox beside "Developer".